# Adding custom key value in a mapped Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So, i have a csv in the following format

```
| index | origin | Limit | Date 
   1        'XYZ'   500     01/05/2020  
   2        'BBC'   254     01/07/2020
```

so i parsed the csv using csvtojson libray and write it to a another json file

```
  csvtojson()
    .fromFile('Data.csv')
    .then((json) => {
      const newArrayOfObj = json.map((item) => {
        let month = item['Date'].split('/')[1];
        return {
          indessx: item['?Index'],
          type: item['origin'],
          number: item['limit'],
          month:  convertNumberToMonth(month),
          date: item['Date'],
        };
      });


      fs.writeFileSync(
        'output.json',
        JSON.stringify(newArrayOfObj),
        'utf-8',
        (err) => {
          if (err) return err;
        }
      );
      console.log('Data successfully loaded!');
    });
```

Now, i have created another helper function which will just convert the month(in number) to an actual month name, following is the helper function.

```
let monthNames = [
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dec',
];

const convertNumberToMonth = (number) => {
  if (number === undefined) return;
  return monthNames[number];
};

module.exports = convertNumberToMonth;
```

So, the problem is that i am not able to convert the month using the helper function, it gets undefined, in the json file.

this is what i get,in array of objects format.

```
[{
    indessx: '100',
    type: 'E',
    number: '765',
    month: undefined,
    date: '08/08/20' }]
```

Comment: Convert `month` to a number before passing it into your function: `Number(month)`

Comment: You also might need to offset `number` by 1 to get valid results since arrays start at 0: `monthNames[number-1]`

Comment: @NickParsons yes did that also thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `string.split()` on a plain string object, it returns a string:

```js
> let item = {'Date': '01/05/2020'}; 
undefined
> let month = item['Date'].split('/');
undefined
> month;
[ '01', '05', '2020' ]
> month[1];
'05'
```

Then it will be `monthNames['05']`, using the string `'05'` as the key to getting value. But `monthNames` isn't an object nor a Map, so it returns `undefined`.

You gonna need to convert the number to a `Number` object. You can do this either in your function(careful if the argument isn't a number, it will give `NaN`), or before pass the `number` argument into the function.

Anyway, add `Number(number)`, or just `+number` like below:

```js
> let monthNames = [
...   'Jan',
...   'Feb',
...   'Mar',
...   'Apr',
...   'May',
...   'Jun',
...   'Jul',
...   'Aug',
...   'Sep',
...   'Oct',
...   'Nov',
...   'Dec',
... ];
undefined
> const convertNumberToMonth = (number) => {
...   if (number === undefined) return;
...   return monthNames[+number - 1];
... };                                                                                                                                                                                            undefined                                                                                                                                                                                         > let item = {'Date': '01/05/2020'};
undefined
> let month = item['Date'].split('/');
undefined
> convertNumberToMonth(month[1]);
'May'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `convertNumberToMonth` function, `number` is a string, such as '08'.

So when you're trying to access the index '08' of the array `monthNames` i.e., `monthNames['08']` you're getting an undefined value, since it doesn't exist.

You can try parsing `number` as an integer, which should solve your problem,

```js
const convertNumberToMonth = (number) => {
  if (number === undefined) return;
  return monthNames[parseInt(number)]; // Convert to int
};
```